# clipboard.js modal window 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I initiate clipboard.js:

```
        new Clipboard('#copy', {
            container: document.getElementById('.product-modal')
        });
```

However I have 2 inputs in the modal window. First one is being selected on load. When I need to copy second one I need to manually select text and click copy. How to solve the problem so when clicked copy button text is automatically copied from the right input?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        new Clipboard('#copy', {
            target: function(trigger) {
                return trigger.previousElementSibling;
            }
        });
    });
```